# Whenever I run this file I get a IndexError: string index out of range, not sure where I'm going wrong here

Tags: python, debugging, indexing, index-error

First, post so sorry if this isn't the right way to format everything but I'm trying to make a connect 4 game for two players and I can't figure out why I'm getting this error.

```
#Creates the board
def Boardmaker(field):
    for row in range(12): #0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
        NewRow = int(row/2)
        if row%2 == 0:
            for column in range(13):
                NewColumn = int(column/2)
                if column%2 == 0:
                    if column != 12:
                        print(field[NewColumn][NewRow],end="")
                    else:
                        print(field[NewColumn][NewRow])
                else:
                    print("|",end="")
        else:
            print("-------------")

#Play space
player = 1       #0    1    2    3    4    5    6
Currentfield = [[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], 
                [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], 
                [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], 
                [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], 
                [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], 
                [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], 
                [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]]

#Player Controller and turn allocator
Boardmaker(Currentfield)
while(True):
    MoveColumn = int(input("Please enter a column"))
    if player == 1:
        #if Currentfield[MoveColumn] == " ":
            Currentfield[MoveColumn] = "X"
            player = 2
    else:
        #if Currentfield[MoveColumn] == " ":
            Currentfield[MoveColumn] = "O"
            player = 1
    Boardmaker(Currentfield)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code

```
if player == 1:
    #if Currentfield[MoveColumn] == " ":
        Currentfield[MoveColumn] = "X"
        player = 2
```

you are replacing one of the lists of `Currentfield` with the string `"X"` since you are not specifying the row index. Then, while printing the game board you iterate over this string, and since this is a string of length 1 you get the index error.

Comment: Cheers man, I didn't realize that could happen and I don't think I'd have noticed that one by myself :3

Answer (score 1):

In a connect 4 game you have to set the `column` and the `row` of the board, doing that your code will be:

```
player = 1
Currentfield = [[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]]
while(True): 
    MoveColumn = int(input("Please enter a column:"))    
    MoveRow = int(input("Please enter a row:"))
    if player == 1:
        #if Currentfield[MoveColumn] == " ":
        Currentfield[MoveColumn][MoveRow] = "X"
        player = 2
    else:
        #if Currentfield[MoveColumn] == " ":
        Currentfield[MoveColumn][MoveRow] = "O"
        player = 1            
    Boardmaker(Currentfield)
```

Also, I noticed that you don't use correctly the indexes of the list, first the `row` and then the `column`, the code above should work in your program but, if you want to change it, you just have to change `field[NewColumn][NewRow]` with `field[NewRow][NewColumn]` and `Currentfield[MoveColumn][MoveRow]` with `Currentfield[MoveRow][MoveColumn]`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that for this particular task I can only use the [MoveColumn] as player input, so I can build the board with rows and columns but I can't directly ask the player to input a row. :3